# MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type

Tags: javascript, opencv

I've build `opencv.js` but when loading it on webpage, it is showing me following error:

```
The script from “http://localhost:3000/images/assets/opencv.js” was loaded even though its MIME type (“text/html”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type.[Learn More] enlarge_image2
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://localhost:3000/images/assets/opencv.js”.
```

The code to load the `opencv.js` is:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'assets/opencv.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

The problem is that I'm not able to use `cv.onRuntimeInitialized` property to know when the `opencv.js` is properly loaded or not. The html webpage is implemented on ruby on rails partial.

[opencv.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hCHgQ75-mNgM_kcQR-6DKC0oufgUIkyt)